# Storyboard tab bar issues

Tags: ios, xcode

Whenever I use the tab bar, the images show but when it's time to build and run, the images are disappear.
Is there a way to fix this issue?

[image: Tab bar issues]

Comment: 1) show code, 2) what does this have to do with the tab bar?

Comment: try loading the image into a uiimageview to see if it loads, if it doesn't then it might be an issue with the image itself

Comment: i tired the image seems fine

Comment: This usually happens when you give an image initially and then change later on. if that is the case, try uninstalling the app, delete the derived data, quit Xcode. Restart everything and you should be good to go.